# The series of $\sin A$, when $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, convergence-divergence

I have to solve this problem for university.

$\sin A$ is defined for every $n \times n$ matrix $A$ as: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n A^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}  \tag{$\star$} $$

**Prove that**

a) $\| \sin A \| \le \sin \| A \|$, where $\| A \| = \max \limits _{1 \le i \le n} | a_{i,i} |$

b) $(\star)$ is convergent

c) We define $f(t) = \sin tA, \ f \in C^2 (\Bbb R)$; then $f$ solves the equation:

$$X''+ A^2X=0 .$$

My attempted solutions:

a) $$\| \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n A^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \| \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty |\frac{(-1)^n }{(2n+1)!}|\|A^{2n+1}\|$$

and $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{(2n+1)!}\|A^{2n+1}\| \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty |\frac{(-1)^n }{(2n+1)!}|\|A^{2n+1}\| $$

so $$\| \sin A \| = \| \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n A^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \| \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{(2n+1)!}\|A^{2n+1}\| = \sin \| A \|$$

but I am really not sure about this!

b) $\sin \|A\| $ is absolutely convergent, that's why sin A is convergent

c) I can write sin(tA) with my series as:

$$ f(t) = tA - \frac{t^3 A^3}{3!} + \frac{t^5 A^5}{5!} - \frac{t^7 A^7}{7!} + ....$$

$$ f'(t) = A - \frac{t^2 A^3}{2!} + \frac{t^4 A^5}{4!} - \frac{t^6 A^7}{6!} + ....$$

$$ f''(t) = -A^3 t + \frac{t^3 A^5}{3!} - \frac{t^5 A^7}{5!} + .... = -A^2 f(t)$$

Is it really okay to differentiate a matrix just as a function? I've never done this before, so I am really sceptical...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean $f(t):=\sin (tA)$?

Comment: Yes!! Sorry, my mistake!

Comment: I've just changed it, thanks for noticing! :-)

Comment: No worries - do you have any attempted solutions for this problem?

Comment: Yes, I will edit it again and write my attempted solutions into it

Comment: The first inequality is not true. It fails for example for $n=1$ and $A=3\pi/2$.

Comment: Perhaps a) ought to be $\vert\vert\sin(A)\vert\vert\leq \sinh(\vert\vert A\vert\vert)$? Though I suppose that requires a definition of $\sinh$, which the question doesn't yet give us.

Comment: I just wrote here what's written on my sheet - so maybe my lecturer made a mistake - @ Martin  and @ πr8 if that's the case, we can't solve a) - I will mention the mistake !

Comment: @Frosi Yep, as it stands a) is incorrect. I would note that in your attempted solution, you place absolute value signs around a term involving $(-1)^n$ - note that $ \vert (-1)^n\vert = 1$ for all $n$. Re: the differentiation question, write out $f(t)$ as a series, differentiate it twice with respect to $t$, and you should be able to prove what you believe.

Comment: Ok, I will try c again and edit my post - can you just tell me if my ideas for b are correct? Thank you so much!